# Show job, total number of employees under each job from emp table

Tags: sql, oracle11gr2

I want output like:

```
----------

 job          count          ename
----------
salesman      4            name1
                           name2
                           name3
                           name4

clerk         4            name1
                           name2
                           name3
                           name4
manager       3            name1
                           name2
                           name3
analyst       2            name1
                           name2
president     1            name
```

.......and so on.

It shoud not repeat the job title and count for each name in that job.  I have got an answer with repetition.

Comment: Please review the [help] on **how to ask a question**. Show the schema, sample data, your attempted query, etc.

Comment: You need to learn about SQL JOINs.  Googling for "SQL JOIN tutorial" should give you a wealth of references.  From there, make a try at your query and then we can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c983c/9)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE employee
    ("job" varchar2(9), "ename" varchar2(5))
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO employee ("job", "ename")
         VALUES ('salesman', 'name1')
    INTO employee ("job", "ename")
         VALUES ('salesman', 'name4')
    INTO employee ("job", "ename")
         VALUES ('clerk', 'name1')
    INTO employee ("job", "ename")
         VALUES ('clerk', 'name2')
    INTO employee ("job", "ename")
         VALUES ('manager', 'name1')
    INTO employee ("job", "ename")
         VALUES ('manager', 'name2')
    INTO employee ("job", "ename")
         VALUES ('manager', 'name3')
    INTO employee ("job", "ename")
         VALUES ('salesman', 'name2')
    INTO employee ("job", "ename")
         VALUES ('salesman', 'name3')
    INTO employee ("job", "ename")
         VALUES ('clerk', 'name3')
    INTO employee ("job", "ename")
         VALUES ('president', 'name')
    INTO employee ("job", "ename")
         VALUES ('clerk', 'name4')
    INTO employee ("job", "ename")
         VALUES ('analyst', 'name1')
    INTO employee ("job", "ename")
         VALUES ('analyst', 'name2')
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT case when j."ename" = firstname then j."job" else ' ' end as job, 
       case when j."ename" = firstname then cast(c.cnt as varchar(5)) else ' ' end as "count", 
       j."ename"
FROM employee j
INNER JOIN (SELECT "job",  min("ename") as firstname, count(*) as cnt FROM employee GROUP BY "job") c ON c."job" = j."job"
ORDER BY cnt desc, j."job", j."ename"
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c983c/9/0)**:

```
|       JOB | COUNT | ENAME |
|-----------|-------|-------|
|     clerk |     4 | name1 |
|           |       | name2 |
|           |       | name3 |
|           |       | name4 |
|  salesman |     4 | name1 |
|           |       | name2 |
|           |       | name3 |
|           |       | name4 |
|   manager |     3 | name1 |
|           |       | name2 |
|           |       | name3 |
|   analyst |     2 | name1 |
|           |       | name2 |
| president |     1 |  name |
```

Comment: I got the same o/p but not as expected after using your solution. I got error after using double quotes for ename,job so I removed it